# How can I efficiently save data from geopandas to django (converting from shapely to geodjango)?

Tags: python, django, geodjango, geopandas, shapely

I am manipulating GIS data w/ `geopandas` and storing it in various `Django` models.  `geopandas` uses `shapely` under-the-hood while `Django` does not.

Here is some code:

```
import geopandas as gpd
from django.contrib.gis.db import models

class MyModel(models.Model):
  geometry = models.PolygonField()
  name = models.CharField(max_length=255, null=False, unique=True)
  some_property = models.IntegerField()

gdf = gpd.read_file("some_data.geojson")
# ...do some stuff w/ gdf...

for data in gdf.to_dict("records"):
  name = data.pop("name")
  MyModel.objects.create_or_update(
    name=name,
    defaults=data,
  )
```

The above will fail w/ errors like:

> TypeError: Cannot set MyModel SpatialProxy (POLYGON) with value of type: <class 'shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon'>

Unless I add some icky code like:

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import fromstr, Polygon 
data["geometry"] = Polygon(fromstr(str(data["geometry"])))
```

Is there any way to avoid this and directly map from `shapely` to `Django`?

---

**edit**:

Here are some values:

```
>> data["geometry"]
<shapely.geometry.polygon.Polygon object at 0x7fb374f41908>
>> str(data["geometry"])
'POLYGON ((-4.337076919429241 53.41842814531255, -4.336698521348041 53.4182242737367, ....))'
>> fromstr(str(data["geometry"]))
<Polygon object at 0x7fb3733d158e>
```

Comment: How does an entry from `data['geometry']` looks like?

Comment: @JohnMoutafis - I have edited my question w/ the information you asked for.

Answer (score 2):

Your solution doesn't seem as icky as you might think.

Since your `data['geometry']` field returns a `WKT` string representation (`'POLYGON ((-4.337076919429241 53.41842814531255, ... ))`) you can avoid the `fromstr` step and pass it directly [to a GEOSGeometry](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/gis/geos/#creating-a-geometry):

```
from django.contrib.gis.geos import GEOSGeometry

polygon = GEOSGeometry('POLYGON ((-4.337076919429241 53.41842814531255, ... ))')
```

You can also add some error handling and stop worrying about you solution falling apart :) :

```
for data in gdf.to_dict("records"):
    name = data.pop("name")
    geometry_str = data.pop('geometry')        
    try:
        geometry = GEOSGeometry(geometry_str)
    except (TypeError, ValueError) as exc:
        # If the geometry_str is not a valid WKT, EWKT or HEXEWKB string
        # or is None then either continue, break or do something else.
        # I will go with continue here.
        continue

    if geometry.geom_type != 'Polygon':
        # If the created geometry is not a Polygon don't pass it on MyModel
        continue 

    MyModel.objects.update_or_create(
        name=name, geometry=geometry,
        defaults=data,
    )
```

Comment: I had to wrap geometry_str in str(geometry_str) to actually get string representation of geometry object for this to work. Thanks!

Comment: @MarjanModerc Good to know :)